# How to use multiprocessing.Manager().Value to store a sum?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to accumulate a sum using multiprocessing.Pool. Here's how I tried:

```
import multiprocessing

def add_to_value(addend, value):
    value.value += addend

with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
    value = manager.Value(float, 0.0)
    with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
        pool.starmap(add_to_value,
                     [(float(i), value) for i in range(100)])
    print(value.value)
```

This gives incorrect and even inconsistent results. For instance, one time it gives 2982.0 and another it gives 2927.0. The correct output is 4950.0, and I do get this when I use only one process in the call to Pool, rather than 2. I'm using Python 3.7.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multiprocessing documentation (under [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value)) is quite explicit about this:

> Operations like `+=` which involve a read and write are not atomic. So if, for instance, you want to atomically increment a shared value it is insufficient to just do `counter.value += 1`.

In short, you need to grab a lock to be able to do this.

You can do that with:

```
def add_to_value(addend, value, lock):
    with lock:
        value.value += addend

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        lock = manager.Lock()
        value = manager.Value(float, 0.0)
        with multiprocessing.Pool(2) as pool:
            pool.starmap(add_to_value,
                         [(float(i), value, lock) for i in range(100)])
        print(value.value)
```

This will correctly output 4950.0.

But note that this approach will be quite expensive due to the need for locking. Most probably, it will take more time to finish than if you have a single process doing the operation.

**NOTE:** I'm also adding an `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard which is actually **required** when using a start method other than *fork*. The default on both Windows and Mac OS is *spawn*, so that's really needed to make this code portable to either of those platforms. Start methods *spawn* and *forkserver* are also available on Linux/Unix, so in some situations this is also needed there.

Multiprocessing will be more efficient when you're able to offload a job to workers that they can complete on their own, for example calculate partial sums and then add them together in the main process. If possible, consider rethinking your approach to fit that model.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to be better at reading documentation in the future.

Comment: @kjs I just like to cite documentation, mainly as an authoritative source for the answers... Good luck with your parallel coding!

Comment: Even if one reads the documentation, IMO it would be easy to miss the subtlety that a `multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager` type of [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Lock) object is needed instead of a [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock).

Comment: @martineau Multiprocessing module has many caveats and quite a few modes of operation. It can be useful in some situations. (This is most likely not one of them.) On Linux (using default "fork" start method), I believe code will raise an exception if you try to pass a mp.Value or mp.Lock to a pool. A manager proxies those, so it's actually safe across process boundaries. Of course, that comes with a cost, so other methods would be preferable here.

Comment: You're right about it raising an exception if an `mp.Lock` is used (on Windows) because that was the approach I tried myself. Note I also added the `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard that the "spawn" start method requires. (BTW, I think you should add the latter to your answer to make it more portable — although I also agree that multiprocessing the example function is probably too inefficient.)

Comment: @martineau Yeah good call! Updated the answer to include a guard.