# Python Multi-Processing Global variable access issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am a beginner in multi processing Python. I have the following code but I am not able to understand why it is not working. Could someone explain me why this is not working.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
db_conn = ""
db_sel = ""

def new_func(i):
    global db_conn, db_sel
    print(db_conn, db_sel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_conn = "56"
    db_sel = "64"
    with Pool() as p:
        p.map(new_func, range(5))
```

I am expecting the output to print 56 64 5 times but the program prints space. Does multiprocessing wont read global variable ?

Comment: I can't reproduce, this prints `56 64` 5 times

Comment: Which Python version are you using ? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: 3.7.9, Mac but I'm pretty sure this should work on any python version/platform

Comment: As an aside, `global db_conn, db_sel` is not necessary

Comment: **Actually** I take it back. Are you on Windows? Move the assignment outside of the `if __name__` block then, because windows processes are started using spawn, not fork, so they wont see whatever happens in the `if __name__` block. Just read that in Python 3.8, spawn became the default for MacOS as well

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga after I moved the code outside if __name__ block it started working. Will check on spawn for better understanding.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If I want those variables inside if __name__ block, what should be done any alternate solution available ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting global variables db_conn and db_sel in the main process, but when the new_func function is executed by the Pool's worker processes, they are working with their own separate copies of these global variables. Hence, the changes made to the global variables in the main process do not affect the worker processes, and the print(db_conn, db_sel) statement in new_func can display empty strings.

Many times it may also work , but behaviour is intermittent. Hence in python 3.8 people has moved away from fork.

https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84559

You can use multiprocessing.Manager, to create objects that can be accessed by different processes.

Something like this should work

```html
    with Manager() as manager:
        db_conn = manager.Value('s', "56")
        db_sel = manager.Value('s', "64")
```

More details on multiprocessing.Manager usage can be found on link
[How to use multiprocessing.Manager().Value to store a sum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646431/how-to-use-multiprocessing-manager-value-to-store-a-sum)